# (Stochastic) matrix for which a stochastic matrix logarithm exists?

Tags: matrices, markov-chains

I think this is basically the inverse question of [Matrices whose exponential is stochastic](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/33230/matrices-whose-exponential-is-stochastic).

i.e. what are sufficient conditions on the matrix representation of an evolution operator of a (finite) discrete Markov chain for it to be embeddable in a continuous Markov chain?

I've found some old paper that may answer this (something about embeddability criteria) but I can't access it as it published in a closed-access journal.

I hope this is a sane question.

Comment: Furthermore, as a modeling bonus question. Is there, in general, a "right" thing to do when you are given one Markov chain and need to pick a transition matrix for a new Markov chain with shorter time intervals? 

Comment: http://arxiv.org/abs/1001.1693

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Steve Hunstman's link above is good:

See the part leading up to Theorem 9 for something relevant to applications:

> The main application of the following
>   theorem may be to establish that
>   certain Markov matrices arising in
>   applications are not embeddable, and
>   hence either that the entries are not
>   numerically accurate or that the
>   underlying process is not autonomous.
>   The theorem is a quantitative
>   strengthening of Lemma 8. It is of
>   limited value except when n is fairly
>   small, but this is often the case in
>   applications.

Also the part on regularization for best compromises when matrices are not embeddable.