# Doubly stochastic matrices as squares of entires of unitary matrices

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, pr.probability, matrices, nonnegative-matrices

Given a unitary matrix $A$ with entries $a_{ii}$, it's clear that the matrix $B$ with entries $b_{ii} = |a_{ii}|^2$ is doubly stochastic.  Is the inverse of this statement true?  Namely, given a doubly stochastic matrix $B'$ with entries $\beta_{ii}$, does there exist a unitary matrix with entries $\alpha_{ii}$ such that $|\alpha|^2_{ii} = \beta_{ii}$?

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/33230/matrices-whose-exponential-is-stochastic/33239#33239

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A brief googling yielded another interesting paper:

http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0024379578900228

Topological properties of orthostochastic matrices ☆

```
Tony F. Heinz
```

"In this paper, it is shown that for n⩾3 the orthostochastic matrices are not everywhere dense in the set of doubly stochastic matrices, thus answering a question of L. Mirsky in his survey article on doubly stochastic matrices [2]"

Comment: That answers the question directly - thank you!

Answer (score 17):

Counterexample:
$$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1/2 & 1/2 \\ 1/2 & 0 & 1/2 \\ 1/2 & 1/2 & 0 \end{pmatrix}.$$
The question is of interest in quantum probability.  Your map from unitary matrices to doubly stochastic matrices defines an interesting region which has non-zero volume, and which cannot be convex because it visits all of the vertices.

Comment: Stochasm is the lowest form of wit.

Comment: @WillJagy Your comment still brings out a belly laugh four years later.

Answer (score 8):

Interesting topic. Today we do not have a clear picture about the relationship between being uni-stochastic (or ortho-stochastic, if you restrict your attention to orthogonal matrices) and doubly-stochastic.

A couple of references:

Defect of a unitary matrix, Wojciech Tadej, Karol Zyczkowski http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0702510

Recent work, it contains a number of references on the discussion.

On the digraph of a unitary matrix, Simone Severini http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0205187

A more combinatorial perspective (but superficial)

Answer (score 4):

Yet another reference

I. Bengtsson, A. Ericsson, M. Kus, W. Tadej, and  K. Zyczkowski, 
Birkhoff's polytope and unistochastic matrices, N=3 and N=4,
 Comm. Math. Phys. 259,  307-324 (2005).